# Need help limiting results of a function at the end of my query

Tags: sql, db2

I have a function below that I'm using under my SELECT statement that I'm trying to limit the results of in my where statement but can't seem to figure out how to name it or tell it to reference that specific function.  I'm thinking I can accomplish this by putting the function in its own WITH statement, but would rather just do it this way if possible.

SELECT
DAYS (CURRENT DATE) - DAYS (DATE(B.TSTAMP)) AS "TRANSIT"

From this function I want to put "WHERE TRANSIT >= '8'"  When I do this now, I get the error "TRANSIT" is not valid in the context where it is used.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that doing it this way is going to flat out ignore any indices.  You're much better off doing something like `WHERE B.TSTAMP >= TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - 8 DAYS, '00:00:00')`  If you need the value of `transit` in the results, you still have to do the subtraction, but at least the comparison will be fast... Does the complete query need something more complicated?

Comment: I hadn't even thought about doing it this way.  That's a lifesaver.  Wish I had thought about that before posting here.  O.o

Comment: For the most part, any time you use a function, type conversion (implicit `CAST(...)`!), or **math** on a column, the query won't be able to use an index for that data.  There are exceptions - I believe `SUBSTRING(<char column> 0, ?)` still will (it can use just the start of the column), and the fact that anything legitimately marked `DETERMINISTIC` can be cached _may_ enable similar behavior.  Still, it's best to perform all operations on host variables (the optimizer _might_ be smart enough to rewrite that for you...).  If you're trying to `GROUP` by `transit`, a Calendar table will help.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Alright, it's working but now it just dawned on me that I need network days rather than calendar days.  Is there a network days function I can incorporate to the line below? AND B.TSTAMP <= TIMESTAMP(CURRENT DATE - 7 DAYS, '00:00:00')

Comment: .... What's a "network" day?  At this point you probably want a Calendar table, with a Boolean `isNetworkDay` column.  Note that for a lot of analysis queries, Calendar tables (and probably some related materialized views) are _ridiculously_ useful.  This site (and the rest of the internet) has some sample tables/construction queries, so figure out what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to something from the `SELECT` clause in your `WHERE`, it processes the `WHERE` first (see [this article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm)).

You can "fix" your problem by pushing your query into a sub-query, and then referring to the name:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DAYS (CURRENT DATE) - DAYS (DATE(B.TSTAMP)) AS "TRANSIT"
    FROM your_table
) A
WHERE TRANSIT >= 8
```

Comment: Is there a difference when it's a CASE statement under the SELECT clause?  For instance, I have a CASE statement ---- END AS "DELIVERED" and I'm able to tell my WHERE to limit when DELIVERED = 'Y'.  That's why I don't understand why I can reference one and not the other.